# Issues with a Photo Gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, gallery

So I'm trying to add a photogallery to my website. There was a .zip file that could be downloaded, with everything needed. I copied those files, replaced & checked so that the filepaths would be correct within the .html file and so on, but this is what happens: http://i49.tinypic.com/2m4ep0y.png

What I am trying to make: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-spectacular-photo-gallery-with-mootools/

The CSS code can be found inside link above, my .css file looks exactly the same, just copy-pasted. The parts from the HTML file were also copied, so not sure where the problem is. Seems like it's not linking to either the javascript/css files? I've tripple-checked the paths and so on.

HTML Code, added inside BODY

```
<div id="container">

<h1>Photo Gallery</h1>

<div id="picture_section">
<div id="inside">

</div>
</div>

<div id="controls_vert">
<div id="up" class="deactivated">Scroll Up</div>
<div id="down">Scroll Down</div>
</div>

<div id="controls_horz">
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="display_picture_container">
<div id="display_picture">Click on the image to go back to the gallery.</div>
<div id="display_picture_img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you included the right version of mootools in your html?

Comment: Well, I just copy-pasted and used the version that was given in the download. The file name is just mootools.js and so is the link in the html file.

Comment: probably css issue. see what you added to the demo what is causing the problem. shot in the dark: make container position:relative;

Comment: Does nothing.. Like, I've basically just copied it and changed the filepaths so that it links correctly, so i got no clue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also downloaded the source file and this is how the code from 'index.html' looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Photo Gallery</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">

<h1>Photo Gallery</h1>

<div id="picture_section">
<div id="inside">

</div>
</div>

<div id="controls_vert">
<div id="up" class="deactivated">Scroll Up</div>
<div id="down">Scroll Down</div>
</div>

<div id="controls_horz">
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
</div>

</div>

<div id="display_picture_container">
<div id="display_picture">Click on the image to go back to the gallery.</div>
<div id="display_picture_img"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

From what i can see in your screenshot it clearely displays nothing. You can change the filepaths of your images and thumbs from `main.js` file by replacing `thumbs/` and `picture/` with your desired folder name. Try to preserve the numerotation name of the files, otherwise it won't show up. Additionaly, you can replace the motools script line with the one specified in the tutorial: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.2.4/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>`

Comment: Let's say I have the .js file in a folder called "js". If I go back once, there's a folder with the .index files, and then I have a folder called images. Inside this I have the thumbs & pictures folders. How would I go about this, the .js file is very confusing to me (as a beginner).

Comment: Did you specified the new path to your js files in html? (ex: `js/motools.js` and `js/main.js`). Also if you placed 'thumbs' and 'pictures' you will need to go to your js folder and open up main.js with WordPad or Notepad. Once opened, specify the new path by changing `pictures/` and `thumbs/` (find them at line: 7,11,38) to `images/pictures/` and `images/thumbs/` and the pictures will show up.

Comment: I ended up using a different photo gallery that works, this is just for a schoolproject so will probably change it later on when I'll start using it as my own website. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Tried your solution as well in a new folder while having my old as a back-up, didn't change anything so I'll stick with the other gallery I have. Thanks anyways!